# Does declaring swap() in namespace foo and then using swap() instead of foo::swap() under the same namespace imply foo::swap()?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

My question is simple. Is it safe to do the following?

Don't need any ethical advice like "Don't name your function swap()!" or whatever, please!

**file1.hpp**

```
//header guards here
#include <utility>  //includes std::swap and std::move

namespace foo 
{
    template<typename T>
    inline void swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)
    {
        T temp = std::move(lhs);
        lhs = std::move(rhs);
        rhs = std::move(temp);
    }
}
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include "file1.hpp"

namespace foo
{
    template<typename T>
    void myfun(T a, T b) 
    { 
        a += b; 
        swap(a, b);  //does it imply foo::swap, because the function
                     //is declared in the foo namespace??
    } 

}
```

Comment: Argument dependent lookup will have no effect, your template is too greedy.

Comment: @DieterLucking You're saying I should say using foo::swap; in the function to make it more charitable?

Comment: Why don't you simply test it with a `std::cout << "Hello world"` statement?

Comment: @DeiDei You are in namespace foo - hence the greedy foo::swap is selected, anyways.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit The thing is, I have a much larger codebase. And occasionally I would get the "call to function is ambiguous" which is fixed by adding the namespace scope in front of it. I wanted to make sure that this is correct, before I made the assumption that something else is wrong in the structure of the project.

Comment: @DeiDei: You can add that single `std::cout` statement to your MCVE (which is almost the code in your question, but with an `int main()`) to get your answer in about 30 seconds flat.

Comment: Thin ice - my comments look wrong (have a look at Loki Astari's answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on the type of `T`.

Argument dependant lookup will find a different `swap()` if the type of `T` is in a different namespace with its own swap. Otherwise it will look in the current namespace.

```
#include <utility>  //includes std::swap and std::move
#include <iostream>

namespace foo
{
    template<typename T>
    inline void swap(T& lhs, T& rhs) {
        std::cout << "foo swap\n";
    }
}
namespace foo
{
    template<typename T>
    void myfun(T a, T b)
    {
        a += b;
        swap(a, b);  // Looks for swap using the type T.
                     // If not found uses the current namespace.
                     // If not found uses the enclosing namespace.
    }

}

namespace baz
{
    class X {
        public:
        X& operator+=(X const& rhs){return *this;}
    };
    inline void swap(X& lhs, X& rhs) {
        std::cout << "Bazz Swap\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    baz::X  a,b;
    foo::myfun(a,b);  // finds ::baz::swap()
}
```

Result:

```
> a.out
Bazz Swap
>
```

Comment: Just as I had an example compiled and ready to show this answer was posted.

Answer (score 2):

It will call `foo::swap`.
You could use `std::swap(a, b);` if you wanted to use the `std` implementation

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. The current namespace is searched first for unqualified names.

Answer (score 1):

It will call `foo::swap()`. There's a common idiom, which is to write

```
using std::swap;
swap( x, y );
```

in generic code. This enables the `std::swap` implementation to kick in. But it also takes `swap()` functions into consideration which are found in other namespaces through argument-dependent look-up (ADL). So if there's a function `foo::swap` and the type of `x` or `y` is in the `namespace foo`, then this `foo::swap` will be called, if it's a better match than `std::swap`.